# Canonical approach for implementing `combineReducers` in existing application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

I have a redux store that up until now has been sufficiently uncomplicated that it required only one reducers file. However I now need to split it up. Using `combineReducers{reducerOne, reducerTwo}` is the way I must refactor my app to go into ever instance of:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  prop1: state.prop1,
  /*...many more...*/
})
```

and change it to:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  prop1: state.reducerOne.prop1,
  /*...many more...*/
})
```

or is there a more canonical way? It could probably be shortened a bit if I got rid of the implicit returns and made the first line `state = state.reducerOne` or something.

#### Is there a better/more-canonical way to incorporate the newly namespaced reducer?

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a good solution to do this.  If you were to add those items into the state like that it would have negative implications for the state the state container is maintaining.  You could copy the value to that level of the object but then it would be duplicated.  If you removed the original value it wouldn't work the way that redux is supposed to natively.

Comment: @JosephFehrman I'm not following. Add which items into the state?

Comment: You can add state.reducerOne.prop1 to the root state component state.prop1.  You can use a spread operator to do this for all properties of reducerOne.  I wouldn't recommend doing it though as it would be a mutation done every iteration of state and I bet Redux would have a hard time handling it.

Comment: @JosephFehrman k thanks

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at these things:

- [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr)
- [normalizr + keyWindow concept talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=thW0yrj3sKU)
- [Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect)
- [ComputingDerivedData Post](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html)
- [react-reselect-and-redux post](https://medium.com/@parkerdan/react-reselect-and-redux-b34017f8194c)

---

Using these tools and approaches, you'll end up 
with having generic selectors exported from your reducers, 
(which are resolving the general purpose data from the sub-state those reducers are responsible for) 
and then imported into the rootReducer 
where they're used to create another set of generic selectors resolving the same data but from the state's root.

And after that there are basically 2 conceptually different ways you can go for:

- keeping component ("container" or "smart" components as we call them) specific selectors 
  alongside with the container components themselves (the example below is more about this particular case)
- Having a separate "data tier" that knows not that much about components it will provide the data for
  and keep data/feature oriented selectors there, organized using patterns you'll define for your project.

Well, of course, you can combine both in some degree.
But it's important to figure out the boundaries and keep all the things where they belong to.

---

`<...>/FooContainer/selectors.js` alongside with your
`<...>/FooContainer/FooContainer.jsx` component.

---

#### `reducers/entities.js`

```
import { INITIAL_STATE } from 'initialState';

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE.entities, action) => {
  /* reducer */
};

export const getModelData = (entities, model, keyWindow) => {
  /*
   get model data from normalized entities store
   using model fields and the keyWindow
  */
};
```

#### `reducers/index.js`

```
// <...>

/* entities, location, contents - are reducers  */
import entities, * as fromEntities from './entities';
import location, * as fromLocation from './location';
import contents, * as fromContents from './contents';

// <...>

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  entities,
  location,
  contents,
});


const getEntities = state => state.entities;
const getLocation = state => state.location;
const getContents = state => state.contents;

// <...>

// this is a generic selector for getting the data from
// the entities store.
export const getModelData = createSelector(
  [getEntities, (state, model, keyWindow) => ({ model, keyWindow })],
  fromEntities.getModelData,
);

// ...
```

#### `FooContainer/selectors.js`

```
import { getModelData } from 'app/reducers';

export const componentData = createSelector(
  [getModelData, (state, model, keyWindow, props) => props],
  (modelData, props) => { /* do something specific for your component */},
);
```

#### `FooContainer/FooContainer.jsx`:

```
import { componentData } from './selectors';
import { FooModel } from 'fooFeature/models';
import { someFooAction, loadFooData } from 'fooFeature/actions';

const getKeyWindow = props => {/* return keyWindow */ };
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  componentData: componentData(state, FooModel, getKeyWindow(props), props),
});
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  someFooAction,
  loadFooData,
};

@connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
class FooContainer extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    componentData: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
    loadFooData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    someFooAction: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }

  /* <...> */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, not sure whether if it fits OP's case, but it's a scalable way to structure redux app.

Comment: @Xlee,  Yeah and maybe it is not even a direct answer to the particular question, but I think it is always good to learn how to do properly right from the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Destructure it maybe:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({reducerOne}) => ({
  prop1: reducerOne.prop1,
  /*...many more...*/
})
```